# How to calculate the length of the string in python

Tags: python, function, string-length

Hello i am a student and i have a few error with my code can anyone help me. **The question is to enter enter a list of words and integer number and return the words if the length of the words is more than the integer.**
This is my answer.

```
def filter_long_words(string):
string = raw_input("Enter a words : ")
n = raw_input("Enter an integer : ")

count = 0
for letter in string:
    count = count + 1
print "The total string are : ", count

return count 

filter_long_words(string)
if count > n:
    print string
```

Comment: what is output you are getting

Comment: While reading integer, cast the return of `raw_input`. To get the length of the string use `len()`, and compare with the integer using `==`

Comment: `count` will give you the count of characters in the string not words

Comment: Do you mean words or a word ?

Comment: @Haris what did you mean by cast the return of  'raw_input' ?  sorry i am very poor in python

Comment: It means that `raw_input` gives you a string. If you want `n` to be an integer you have to do `int(raw_input("Enter an integer : "))`

Comment: @0decimal0 okay i see. I mean words. sorry my mistake

Comment: @Asyiqin are you trying to get a single word from the use of `raw_input` or are you trying to get several words typed for that input? Maybe for example if you had the user type in several words spaced out.

Comment: Try using `split` with string and count it inside a for loop.  Deuce has an answer to your problem with similar solution

Comment: @0decimal0 ok. I've got my answer. Thank you for helping

Comment: @Asyiqin I have updated your question to reflect your comment `enter a list of words`. This should clear things up for future readers.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can get the length of any string with `len()`

example:

```
print (len("string"))
```

result:

```
6
```

Here is a simple example:

In your question you stated that the instruction was to:

> return the words if the length of the words is more than the integer.

The below code will do that:

```
my_str = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
n = raw_input("Enter an integer: ")

def filter_long_words(my_str, n):
    if len(my_str) > int(n):
        return my_str # assigns the results of my_string to some_word

some_word = filter_long_words(my_str, n)

print some_word
```

In response to your question in the comments:

```
def filter_long_words():
    my_str = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
    n = raw_input("Enter an integer: ")
    if len(my_str) > int(n):
        return my_str # assigns the results of my_string to some_word

some_word = filter_long_words()

print some_word
```

One last example. Lets say you are entering several words as one big string.

We can use `.split()` to get each word and test it separately.

```
# simulates raw input of 4 words being typed in at once.
list_of_words_as_a_string = "One Two Three Four"
n = raw_input("Enter an integer: ")

def filter_long_words(word, n):
    if len(word) > int(n):
        print word
        return word # this is only useful if you are doing something with the returned word.

for word in list_of_words_as_a_string.split():
    filter_long_words(word, n)
```

Results when using 3 as the integer:

```
Enter an integer: 3
Three
Four
```

Comment: so the input string and integer should not be include in the function definition?

Comment: They can if you like. you could just move the raw_input to the top of the function and remove the arguments from the function.

Comment: @Asyiqin I have added a 2nd example with the `raw_input` inside of the function

Comment: Don't call your variables `str`.

Comment: @asongtoruin you are correct. I have fixed it in my example.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand if you need to check the length of one word or of several words and only keeps the ones that are long enough. Since others have answered for one word, I am answering for several words :

```
string = raw_input("Enter several words: ")
n = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))


def filter_long_words(string, n):
    long_words = [word for word in string.split() if len(word) > n]
    return long_words

print filter_long_words(string, n)
```

So, if `string = 'one two three four five six'` and `n = 3`, the output will be `['three', 'four', 'five']`.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the way to go . `split` is the option here.

Comment: This is probably what the OP was looking for. `enter a words` was throwing us all off I think.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech sorry it was my mistake it suppose to be `enter a list of words`. What is the function of split?

Comment: @Asyiqin The method split() returns a list of all the words in the string separated by a space. You can see the documentation here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of a string with `len()`

```
string = raw_input("Enter a words : ")
n = int(raw_input("Enter an integer : ")) # convert the input to integer

if len(string) > n :
    print(string)
```

Comment: Your example is fine but the OP was instructed to "return" the word if len of string was more than int given. So the example should be a function I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `len` function to get the length of the string.

i.e.

```
def filter_long_words():
  string = raw_input("Enter a words : ")
  n = raw_input("Enter an integer : ")

  print ("The total string are : ", len(string))
  if len(string) > int(n):
    return string
```

Comment: Your indention is off.

Comment: What's the point of using `string` as an argument if it is later taken as a user input ?

Comment: My intention was to ask to use `len` function to get the string length.

Comment: You did not need to remove the entire code you had in your answer. You could have just moved the use of `len()` into the portion of the code that is comparing the 2 user inputs. And fixed the indention issue.

Answer (score 0):

To find the length of the string without counting the spaces

```py
def StrLx_(my_str):
    #I am defining a function here for it if you don't want it you can 
    #delete this part
      
    space = " "  
    no_space = ""  
    a = 0

    for char in my_str:
        if char not in space:
            no_space = no_space + char

    string = no_space

    while string[a] != string[-1]:
        a = a+1
    
    print(a+1)
```

To find the length of the string with spaces getting counted

```py
def StrL_(my_str):
    #lly here

    a = 0
    
    while my_str[0] != my_str[-1]:
        a = a+1
    
    print(a+1)
```